# Apache POI Generated excel file not saving

Tags: java, selenium, automation, apache-poi

I am using excel template as fileinput stream and then I am writing 1 row in that file after that I am generating a new excel file after wrting the cell values ,Now the issue is everytime i have to open and save the excel file then only my original file size(16kb) is coming up other wise it is showing 13 kb(am using apache poi)

I used the SXXFWORKBOOK also it’s still the same

Comment: Please share your code to be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @pburgr    CODE:
  String downloadPath = "C:\\xyz.xlsx"
          File dir = new File(downloadPath);
                  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dir);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow rw= sh.getRow(1);
        XSSFCell cl=rw.getCell(0,MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
  sh.getRow(1).getCell(0,MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).setCellValue("xyz";
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(downloadPath);
   wb.write(fos);
  fis.close();